# Using Assertj how to verify two hashmap list List<Map<String, String>> with multiple keys

Tags: assertj

I have two hashmap list and want to check the value present against the given key is same.

```
List<Map<String, String>> listMap1 = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Car", "Toyota");
map1.put("Bike", "BMW");
map1.put("ElectricCar", "Tesla");
listMap1.add(map1);

System.out.println(listMap1);

List<Map<String, String>> listMap2 = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("Car", "Toyota");
map2.put("MotorBike", "TVS");
map2.put("ElectricCar", "Tesla");
listMap2.add(map2);
System.out.println(listMap2);
```

using below approach I am able to verify with single key

```
SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softAssertions -> softAssertions.assertThat(listMap2)
          .extracting("Car")
          .contains(listMap1.stream().map(m -> m.get("Car")).toArray()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example only shows singleton list so it looks like it boils down to check that the common keys from the two maps have the same value. Could you show an example with lists that contain multiple maps and what you expect from the assertions?

In the meantime, I was able to do the following (even though I'm not sure that addresses your issue):

Version 1
Extracting multiple values that are returned as a `Tuple` and check that the tuple has the correct content.

```java
assertThat(listMap2).extracting("Car", "ElectricCar")
                    .containsExactly(tuple("Toyota", "Tesla"));
```

Version 2
Instead of hardcoding `"Toyota"` and `"Tesla"`, I assume you want to get the value from `listMap1` with for example a helper method (named `valueOf` here that you can write easily)

```java
assertThat(listMap2).extracting("Car", "ElectricCar")
                    .containsExactly(tuple(valueOf("Car", listMap1), 
                                           valueOf("ElectricCar", listMap1)));
```

This is not a straightforward solution, I would recommend to write an helper method like `checkValuesMatchForSameKeys(List<Map<String, String>> listMap1, Map<String, String> map2)` that you could use as:

```java
assertThat(listMap2).allSatisfy(map2 -> checkValuesMatchForSameKeys(listMap1, map2));
```